# OpenCV-3.4.0 installation:"make -j8" failed

Tags: opencv, makefile, installation

I tried to install opencv-3.4.0 according to the tutorials https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace/wiki/Unix-Installation,
but when I finished `cmake`，then try `make -j8`, it failed at 30%. Does anyone know the solution and can help me? Thank you very much.
All demanding dependencies for OpenCV was installed.

```
[ 29%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o
[ 29%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_videostab
[ 30%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_videostab
[ 30%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_perf_superres
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
In file included from /home/zq/opencv-3.4.0/modules/cudev/include/opencv2/cudev/util/tuple.hpp:50:0,
                 from /home/zq/opencv-3.4.0/modules/cudev/include/opencv2/cudev.hpp:55,
                 from /home/zq/opencv-3.4.0/modules/core/src/cuda/gpu_mat.cu:52:
/home/zq/opencv-3.4.0/modules/cudev/include/opencv2/cudev/util/detail/tuple.hpp:49:26: fatal error: thrust/tuple.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o.cmake:208 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/zq/opencv-3.4.0/build/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o


modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/build.make:63: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1730: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Do you want install OpenCV or OpenFace? Your link points to OpenFace. And why don't you use your package manager to install OpenCV?

Comment: `fatal error: thrust/tuple.h: No such file or directory` indicates that you have an incomplete source set, or perhaps compiled things in the wrong order.

Comment: Do you have [`thrust`](https://thrust.github.io/) installed?  That appears to be what it's looking for.